# Correct way to insert a view with Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, zepto

I have a simple backbone.js app. I want to render a view into the DOM of the HTML page, this view is a detail view for a model. My HTML page already has the DIV element that I want to render the view into. If I try to render my view like this:

```
detailView = new RulesPanelView({model : @model})
$("#detail").html(detailView.render().el)
```

It fails and I get [Object HTMLDivElement] inserted into the DOM, not my rendered HTML.

This is the only way I can get it to work and it seems like a hack:

```
$("#detail").html('')
detailView = new RulesPanelView({model : @model})
$("#detail").append(detailView.render().el)
```

Having to empty the HTML of the DIV before rendering so I don't get multiple views rendered inside #detail which is what would happend with append.

Also aren't I creating way too many views this way, just seems cleaner to replace the HTML as in the first code segment?

What is the correct way to render this view?

Comment: The first code segment should work as that is how I have stuff set up in my controllers. `$('#content').html(currentView.render().el)`. Arthur Debert's solution should work as well. Can you show us the code to RulesPanelView?

Answer (score 6):

What you want is to pass the already inserted DOM node to the view as a 'el' option to the constructor:

```
new RulesPanelView({el: $("#detail")});
```

This way, it won't render again. You still need to make sure your view's 'render' method will be able to render a correct view from an updated model, though.

The [backbone documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-constructor) mentions this  as a good way to avoid rendering too much stuff at once.

Comment: Yes this does work. However there is one issue. Any events that I have assigned in RulesPanelView get reassigned on every render. So if it renders twice the DOM only contains the latest render BUT the click event fires twice. 

These events are set using the events hash in the view.

Comment: No events should be reassigned on every render(). Assuming you only put events in `events: {},` attribute on the view or in the `initialize` block, events are only bound when you initialize the object. You should be aware though that the events block in Backbone uses JQuery's `.live()` and note `.bind()`

Comment: Appears that this is not the case. Every re-render causes another event to be bound. I WOULD have expected it to remove the events before a render. Think i'm going to go without a framework Backbone has caused me no end of problems and issues plus help is very lacking.

Comment: If you override the view's 'remove' method, and remove the older element with jQuery's remove, assuming you've used 'live' or 'delegate' events, you should be all set.

Comment: Backbone uses delegate from jquery, not live.

Answer (score 1):

I actually append *in* the `render` method of the view. This doesn't work if you want to re-render when models change - but for that I've added a `refresh` method that render actually calls before appending. I then bind the refresh to the model change (if I need that). So in my View, I do this:

```
render: function(){
    var markup = this.refresh();
    $(markup).appendTo('#some-selector');
    return this;
}, 
refresh: function(){
    return $(this.el).html($.mustache(this.template, this.model.toJSON()));
},
```

Not sure if that's the "best", but I think it works pretty well. I've also seen where you have a collection bound to a view that loops through all of the models and renders "sub-views" of the collection view - this provides a nicer programmatic approach than hard-coding where you're going to append.

Comment: This is not what the Backbone documentation recommends (http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-render), and as you are noting it causes problems, like appending it twice when the model changes, that you have to hack around. I'd also be worried about the coupling to the containing structure (#some-selector) that this introduces.